# Show $\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{2}{k^2-1}= \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Show that
$$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{2}{k^2-1}= \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$$
with the hint, "Write out the first six and last two terms. Then group them in pairs of two."

Additionally, rewrite the series as a telescoping series.

The first six and last two terms are: 
$$2/3 + 2/8 + 2/15 + 2/24 + 2/35 + 2/48 + 2/63 + ... + 2/(4n^2 - 1) + 2/((2n + 1)^2 - 1)$$

However, I fail to see how I should group them.

I'm also at a complete loss in regards to rewriting the series as a telescoping series.

Edit: All right, so

$$\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{k - 1} - \frac{1}{k + 1}$$
$$1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{2n + 1} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n + 1}$$
$$= (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}) + (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{5}) + (\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6}) + (\frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{7}) - \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{2n + 1} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n + 1} $$

I'm not sure where to go with the last two terms.

Edit edit: Thanks everyone! I got it!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac2{k^2-1}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1{k+1}$$

Comment: telescoping sums for the win. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. In this telescoping series, the first and last two terms remain unpaired, so they do not cancel out -- they're still there in the sum.